# Send parameters in instance method (Mongodb/mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I wanted to send in a parameter inside an instance method, what is the way to do this?

```
var User = new Schema({
    following: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    followers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

User.methods.follow = function(otherUser, cb) {
  this.following.push(otherUser);
  this.save(cb);
};

User.methods.unfollow = function(otherUser, cb) {
  var index = this.following.indexOf(otherUser._id);
  if (index >= 0)
  {
    this.following.splice(index, 1);
    this.save(cb);
  }
};
```

Can I pass "otherUser" in like that? If not, should I be using static methods to accomplish this?

The issue i'm having is that whenever I try to use the method, i get "has no method 'follow'". I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong....
I should mention that I am using passport for authentication. Not sure if that has any impact on what I'm seeing...

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it.  Is it not working for you?

Comment: @JohnnyHK : I keep getting has no method 'follow' whenever I try to do user1.follow(user2, function...)

Comment: how do you instantiate user1? Can you share related code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks about right to me. The only side note is that you could use *`this.following.pull({_id: otherUser})` instead of your `splice`.

- Assuming you're passing user's id.